# Striped table in HTML

Tags: html, css

my table is Look like this. I tried to striped it as you see in blow :

```css
   tr:nth-child(even)  {
   background-color:#AD0D10;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
    <th >xxx</th>
    <th >xxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>888888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88888</td>
    <td colspan="3">888888</td>
    <td>8888</td>
    <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>888888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88888</td>
    <td colspan="3">888888</td>
    <td>8888</td>
    <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

aside from Header, In the table, each row contains two . If I take that row as the main row. I want to have the main rows striped. In fact,I want both  are colored together. 
I use tr:nth-child(even)> tr but it still not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "main" and "sub"?

Comment: not sure about what you want, but have you ever tried tr:nth-child(odd)?

Comment: Do you mean you want stripped columns and not stripped rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to recognise is that your CSS:

```
`tr:nth-child(even)`
```

Is doing exactly what you asked it to do; the fact that you have the first cell in each row spanning multiple rows doesn't mean that the `<tr>` itself becomes larger, it just means that that `<td>` now occupies space in each row.

So, to work around that, we need to style every alternate pair of `<tr>` elements; which is accomplished using two `:nth-child()` selectors:

```
// selecting every fourth <tr> element within the <tbody> element:
tbody tr:nth-child(4n),
// selecting the <tr> element that precedes every fourth <tr>
// element within the <tbody>:
tbody tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(4n),
tbody tr:nth-child(4n-1) {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>xxx</th>
      <th>xxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nwgxzj5h/).

Notes:

- I've extended the `<table>` by copying and pasting the first two 'row groups' in order to demonstrate that the pattern extends beyond the simple demo, and
- I've also wrapped the `<tr>` row containing the `<th>` elements in its own `<thead>` element for two reasons:

  1. Because it's semantically where the table column-headings should be, and
  2. To prevent the `tr:nth-child()` selector from selecting the `<tr>` containing those elements the `<tr>` elements in the table-body needed to be distinguished from the `<tr>` containing the `<th>` elements; because that required grouping with a `<tbody>` it made sense to also use a `<thead>` for the headings.

With regards to your terminology there is no "main" or "sub" row; there are only rows (despite the row-spanning `<td>` elements).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).
- HTML:

  - [`<tbody>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).
  - [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td).
  - [`<th>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th).
  - [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).

Answer (score 1):

Is your colspan column always on first position?

If yes see example below.

If not go to Irina's answer :)

```css
tr:nth-child(even) td:not(:first-child)  {
   background-color:#AD0D10;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
    <th >xxx</th>
    <th >xxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
    <th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>888888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88888</td>
    <td colspan="3">888888</td>
    <td>8888</td>
    <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>888888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>88888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
    <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>88888</td>
    <td colspan="3">888888</td>
    <td>8888</td>
    <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit unclear what you want, but could you try an example below. Hope it helps.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) + tr {
   background-color:#AD0D10;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th >xxx</th>
      <th >xxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxxxx</th>
      <th>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>888888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>88888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
      <td>8888888</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>88888</td>
      <td colspan="3">888888</td>
      <td>8888</td>
      <td colspan="4">8888888</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```